# How to properly wrap my data layer to communicate with business logic

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework

I have an EF Core data layer and i want to wrap it around an interface to separte it from the business logic.
Now the issue is that i am not sure i am doing it correctly.
First, i was just using static context to be alive all the time but that seems just wrong to me.

Should i create a new instance of context for each request? Then i think it would cause issue with entity tracking and changes i make will not save when SaveChanges is called. 
Should i even return an EF entity object or just a model object to not expose data related to the database

Tldr: i just need some direction on how to wrap my EF Core data layer correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the repository pattern

```
public class MyRepo : IMyRepo
{
    public MyRepo(string connectionString) {
        ... instantiate DB context
    }
    public MyObject GetObjectById(string id) {
        ...EF stuff goes in here
    }

    ... more methods that return business objects
}
```

Inject via a DI framework in your app. Use Singleton or per request context as appropriate

Comment: When is it appropriate to use singleton and when is it to use per request.

Comment: that depends on your application. I think in most cases you are good with a singleton when your connection string is constant

Comment: Okay. One more question. Lets say i have a class person that represents a database table and mapped by ef core. Now if the business layer request a person object from the repo class should i return just the original object fetched by ef or create another class for example, personModel and return it instead of the person object that is mapped to the db

Comment: for complete separation, the models returned by the repo should not have any EF attributes or other references to EF dlls.